# Load Balancing Cookies for Authentication in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to setup refresh tokens for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor app.  I found an example [here](https://github.com/mderriey/aspnet-core-token-renewal/blob/master/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs).  It uses cookies to pass the access token and refresh token to another part of the application.

My concern is that the cookies will not work when it is hosted in a load balanced way.  (I read this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but it does not really clarify this for me.)

How do cookies travel in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor app?  Do they get sent to the client which then sends them up with each request?  If so, each node in the load balancing pool would get the cookie and be able to use the information in it, right?

Comment: You can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501066/6751634

Comment: do you get any solution for this.

Comment: @sina_Islam - Not for razor specifically, but for ASP.Net Core in general, the cookie seems to be sent with each request.